How do we change the position of the dialogflow messenger as we drag the icon from the bottom right to the left?
I have added dragging functionality to the icon, and now when I move it from the right to the extreme left of the screen, the messenger window appears to go off-screen. What can we do about this?

I couldn't find any documentation addressing this issue. As we continue dragging the icon, the chatbox window's position should adjust from right to left. As an example, I have attached a link below. Please try moving the chatbox icon from right to left and observe how the chatbox window adjusts accordingly. The chatbox window should not go off-screen but should remain within the screen boundaries.
https://pizzaonline.dominos.co.in/

Hi @Marcus, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
